# Audio player with album cover as background image

Tags: javascript, css, html, bootstrap-4

How can I make an audio player with album cover image as the background image such that all playing control buttons be on top of that image. I have used this

```
<audio controls = 'controls'>
    <source src='' type= 'audio/mp3'>
</audio>
```

but it does not allow me to add an image, I have googled a lot with no success.

Comment: Hmmm. Div with background you want and audio tag positioned on top of image?

Comment: yes, something like that but I don't think if it is good idea to use div with background image!

Comment: May I ask why div is a bad idea?

Comment: Thank you, finally the idea of putting div background worked fine.

Comment: Haha, Glad I could help. I posted an answer if you'd like to mark it

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```html
<video controls poster='img/album/png'>
    <source src='' type= 'audio/mp3'>
</video>
```

Comment: are you sure it works?  I have tried and tried and it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

You can position a `div` as relative, size it as you need and place the audio player inside the div as absolute.

https://jsfiddle.net/os2yd6x3/1/

```
<div class="audioPlayer">
  <audio controls = 'controls'>
    <source src='' type= 'audio/mp3'>
  </audio>
</div>

.audioPlayer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url('http://arbordayblog.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/tree.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.audioPlayer audio{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%
}
```

Comment: I also put an image (album cover) as the background image of the div

Comment: Yes :). I used a BG color to represent the background image. I did update my fiddle with an image

Answer (score 2):

You can grab album cover from `media tags` of audio file using [jsmediatags](https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags).

And then put it to div background.

Example - [ID3 Reader](http://web.ist.utl.pt/antonio.afonso/www.aadsm.net/libraries/id3/#demo)